# Rails app is using wrong bundler version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I've a Rails app that needs to use bundler version

```
gem "bundler", ">= 2.2.17", "<= 2.2.30"
```

I've installed bundler version 2.2.30 using `gem install bundler:2.2.30 --default`. Running `gem list bundler` returns the following

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 2.2.30)
```

but the issue is that `bundler version` returns a different version(`2.1.2`) than `2.2.30`. It returns

```
Bundler version 2.1.2
```

`which bundler` gives

```
/Users/masroor/.rbenv/shims/bundler
```

and whenever I try to bundle the app using `bundle _2.2.30_ install` or try running rails server/console, it does not pick up the right bundler version(`2.2.30`) instead it uses `2.1.2`
Trying to do `bundle _2.2.30_ install` fails with this error

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
> In Gemfile:
> bundler (>= 2.2.17, <= 2.2.30)
> Current Bundler version:
> bundler (2.1.2)
> This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
> Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
> Could not find gem 'bundler (>= 2.2.17, <= 2.2.30)' in any of the relevant sources:
> the local ruby installation

The `gem env` installation path does not contain the bundler gemspec against `2.1.2` bundler version.

Output of `gem env`

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.0 (2019-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin19]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/masroor/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/masroor/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/masroor/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/masroor/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/masroor/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/masroor/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-19
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/masroor/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
     - /Users/masroor/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/masroor/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec
     - /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin
     - /Users/masroor/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/masroor/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin
     - /Users/masroor/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
     - /Library/Apple/bin
```

The installed gemspecs for `bundler`, returned by `ls /Users/masroor/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/specifications/default/ | grep bundler` are

```
bundler-2.2.30.gemspec
```

I'm using `rbenv` for ruby version management, running `ruby -v` returns

```
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-darwin19]
```

`which ruby` returns

```
/Users/masroor/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

I tried to find files pertaining to bundler 2.1.2 in my filesystem with

```
find / -type f -name bundler | grep bundler | grep 2.1.2
```

and found the following

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/masroor/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/libexec/bundler
/Users/masroor/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/libexec/bundler
```

when I try to uninstall bundler version `2.1.2` with `gem uninstall bundler:2.1.2` I get

```
Gem 'bundler' is not installed
```

Comment: Check `BUNDLED_WITH` clause of your `Gemfile.lock`. Does it say `2.1.2`? Try `bundle update --bundler` is so...

Comment: `bundle _2.2.30_ install` does not succeed so I don't get a `Gemfile.lock` at all, I've updated the question with the error that I get when I try to do bundle install step. Please check.

Comment: and if I try `bundle update --bundler` without having the `Gemfile.lock`, I get this message `This Bundle hasn't been installed yet. Run `bundle install` to update and install the bundled gems.`

Comment: as a last resort, I removed the `bundler` version constraints from the Gemfile;`gem "bundler", ">= 2.2.17", "<= 2.2.30"`, and changed it to `gem "bundler"` and then I could successfully run `bundle install` and the `rails server` started fine.